# PowerShell String Collection - Search

Tags: powershell

I found some strange behavior in PowerShell, and can't figure out why it behaves this way.  Out of the three following lines of code, why is it that only `-match` returns what I want, and the other two commands return nothing?

```
Get-Service | ?{$_.Name -like "sql"}
Get-Service | ?{$_.Name.Contains("sql")}
Get-Service | ?{$_.Name -match "sql"}      # This one works?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-like` uses a wildcard match. If you don't use any wildcards, it will do an exact match (not case-sensitive).

The `.Contains` method of the `[String]` object is case-sensitive.

The `-match` operator uses a regular expression (not case-sensitive). Since the input string (the name of the service) exists in your pattern, it returns `$true`.